# shows error on all topic name field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form where user gets to post the topics. Beneath that the posted topic is shown. When there is the validation error in one of the topic name or type field then all the name or type field is shown with name or topic required. why is that so? The validation in onChange event is not behaving normally.

Here is the code

This if for the validation

```
export const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  const requiredFields = {
    topic_name: 'Topic Name',
    topic_type: 'Topic Type',
  }
  for (const key in requiredFields) {
    if(requiredFields.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(!values[key]) {
        errors[key] = `${requiredFields[key]} is required`
      }
    }
  }
  return errors
}
```

topic

```
class Topic extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customTopic: [],
            visible: false,
            id: '',
            topic_name: this.props.match.params.topic || '',
            topic_type: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCustomTopic();
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    simplePlainTable = topics => (
        <DataTable plain>
            <TableHeader>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableColumn>Topic Name</TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn>Topic Type</TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn>Action</TableColumn>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHeader>
            <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableColumn>
                        <Field
                            placeholder="Topic Name"
                            name="topic_name"
                            id="topic_name"
                            value={this.state.topic_name}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            className="input-field"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            component={TopicNameField}
                            required
                        />
                    </TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn>
                        <Field
                            placeholder="Topic Type"
                            name="topic_type"
                            id="topic_type"
                            value={this.state.topic_type}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            required
                            className="input-field"
                            type="text"
                            fullWidth
                            component={TopicTypeField}
                        />
                    </TableColumn>
                    <TableColumn>
                        <Button
                            icon
                            tooltipLabel="Add"
                            onClick={e => this.addCustomTopic(e)}>
                            add
                        </Button>
                    </TableColumn>
                </TableRow>
                {topics &&
                    topics.customTopic.map((obj, i) => (
                        <TableRow key={i} id={obj.id}>
                            <TableColumn>
                                <Field
                                    placeholder="Topic Name"
                                    name="topic_name"
                                    id="topic_name"
                                    defaultValue={obj.topic_name}
                                    onBlur={e =>
                                        this.updateCustomTopic(
                                            { topic_name: e.target.value },
                                            obj.id
                                        )
                                    }
                                    required
                                    className="input-field"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                    component={TopicNameField}
                                />
                            </TableColumn>
                            <TableColumn>
                                <Field
                                    placeholder="Topic Type"
                                    name="topic_type"
                                    id="topic_type"
                                    defaultValue={obj.topic_type}
                                    onBlur={e =>
                                        this.updateCustomTopic(
                                            { topic_type: e.target.value },
                                            obj.id
                                        )
                                    }
                                    required
                                    className="input-field"
                                    type="text"
                                    fullWidth
                                    component={TopicTypeField}
                                />
                            </TableColumn>
                            <TableColumn>
                                <Button
                                    icon
                                    tooltipLabel="Delete"
                                    onClick={() => this.show(obj.id)}>
                                    delete
                                </Button>
                            </TableColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
            </TableBody>
        </DataTable>
    );

    render() {
        const { topics } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                    {this.simplePlainTable(topics)}
                    {this.dialogContainer()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'wizard',
    validate
})(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Topic));
```

I am using redux form.

this is what happening

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple instances of Topic being rendered. Is that accurate? And you're saying if, say, the Topic Name is flagged as invalid in one Topic instance, it also flags it as invalid in the other Topic instances?

Comment: yes that is what happening.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing occurs because both Topic instances are, technically, the same "form". When you call `reduxForm()`, you pass in a form name (`wizard`). This acts as the form's "identifier" and the form's data is stored in redux using this identifier. In other words, when you have two instances of your component being rendered, both instances are sharing the same exact form state in redux.

The way to solve this really depends on your business requirements. Are you rendering multiple Topics at the same time? If so, then you probably want to look into [FieldArray](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/) or [FormSection](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/formsection.md/). If not, then the state from your first Topic form probably just isn't being destroyed before the second Topic form is displayed.

Comment: sorry i did not understand "then the state from your first Topic form probably just isn't being destroyed before the second Topic form is displayed."

Comment: Let's say you have a topic page where you're showing the content of Topic A. Validation occurs and there's an issue so a field is marked invalid. Then, you leave the topic page and click on a link to view Topic B and then you are taken back to the topic page. If the state from Topic A was never cleared out of the redux state, then things like validation errors may be hanging around and showing up even though you're trying to show data for Topic B now.